# Can't access files in wwwroot subdirectories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I've sample asp.net 5 app running in docker container on my VPS (Debian 8) using dnxcore50. App consist only with static files (html, css, js). Both on my local VM running docker and on VPS any files that are not in wwwroot directory eg. /styles/, /components/, /scripts/ cannot be accessed. Requests for this files have status 200, but server doesn't send any data back.

Here is my Configure method:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
        });
    }
```

Project.json file:

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel    --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

and dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/approot/src/WebApplication5
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "web"]
```

Here is ls -l output from my wwwroot directory on VPS

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Jan 26 18:07 Components
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 26 18:07 Images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 26 18:07 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 26 18:07 Styles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9582 Jan 10 20:31 cart.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13569 Jan 10 20:29 category.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10467 Jan 10 20:30 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6282 Jan 15 17:50 login.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13273 Jan  3 17:39 rowsgrid.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4611 Jan 10 20:31 signin.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   396 Jan 26 18:07 web.config
```

And for eg. from /Styles:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14976 Jan 10 20:28 Site.css
```

Comment: You should remove `app.Run(async (context) => { });` as this results in 200 responses for unhandled requests. Without it a default 404 will be sent.

Comment: Thanks. Now it sends 404. But still not quite what I wanted :)

Comment: You should remove app.Run(async (context) => { }); 404 is the correct error code in your case. Be sure that your urls are correct. Url paths are case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that StaticFile paths are case sensitive on linux.

Comment: I've made it all lower case and it works : ) Thank you.